# Return null instead of column value in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entitymanager

I'm getting data from database as below in my Java EE app.

```
WdLeavesSupplier supplier = entityManager.getEntityManager()
        .find(WdLeavesSupplier.class,
                Integer.parseInt(supplier_id));
```

There is a column as `active` in this entity. I have inserted some data into this and value of `active` column is `on` in those records. When i'm retrieving data as above, i'm getting `null` as value of `active` column. Other columns(name, address, etc..) values getting correctly.

Database record like this.

```
supplier_id, supplier_code, supplier_first_name, supplier_last_name, supplier_phone, supplier_address_a, supplier_address_b, center_id, active, comment, created_date
14, 't1', 'Mark', 'Smith', '0711234224', 'g45, new town', 'Galle', 41, 'on', 'test comment', '2014-06-24 17:06:38'
```

Here is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE  `wdtccdb`.`wd_leaves_supplier` (
  `supplier_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `supplier_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `supplier_first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `supplier_last_name` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `supplier_phone` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `supplier_address_a` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `supplier_address_b` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `center_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `active` varchar(5) default NULL,
  `comment` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`supplier_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `supp_code_un` (`supplier_code`),
  KEY `FK_wd_leaves_supplier_center_id` (`center_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_wd_leaves_supplier_center_id` FOREIGN KEY (`center_id`) REFERENCES `wd_collection_center` (`center_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Entity Class [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/umcwnrp0y7b0t5l/WdLeavesSupplier.java)

**Entity Class Code**

```
package com.wd.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * The persistent class for the wd_leaves_supplier database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "wd_leaves_supplier")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "WdLeavesSupplier.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM WdLeavesSupplier u"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "WdLeavesSupplier.findByCode", query = "SELECT u FROM WdLeavesSupplier u WHERE u.supplierCode = :code") })
public class WdLeavesSupplier implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "supplier_id")
    private int supplierId;

    private String active;

    private String comment;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    @Column(name = "supplier_address_a")
    private String supplierAddressA;

    @Column(name = "supplier_address_b")
    private String supplierAddressB;

    @Column(name = "supplier_code")
    private String supplierCode;

    @Column(name = "supplier_first_name")
    private String supplierFirstName;

    @Column(name = "supplier_last_name")
    private String supplierLastName;

    @Column(name = "supplier_phone")
    private String supplierPhone;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to WdLeafPurchase
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wdLeavesSupplier")
    private List<WdLeafPurchase> wdLeafPurchases;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to WdCollectionCenter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "center_id")
    private WdCollectionCenter wdCollectionCenter;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to WdSupplierLoan
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wdLeavesSupplier")
    private List<WdSupplierLoan> wdSupplierLoans;

    public WdLeavesSupplier() {
    }

    public int getSupplierId() {
        return this.supplierId;
    }

    public void setSupplierId(int supplierId) {
        this.supplierId = supplierId;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return this.active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return this.comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Timestamp createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getSupplierAddressA() {
        return this.supplierAddressA;
    }

    public void setSupplierAddressA(String supplierAddressA) {
        this.supplierAddressA = supplierAddressA;
    }

    public String getSupplierAddressB() {
        return this.supplierAddressB;
    }

    public void setSupplierAddressB(String supplierAddressB) {
        this.supplierAddressB = supplierAddressB;
    }

    public String getSupplierCode() {
        return this.supplierCode;
    }

    public void setSupplierCode(String supplierCode) {
        this.supplierCode = supplierCode;
    }

    public String getSupplierFirstName() {
        return this.supplierFirstName;
    }

    public void setSupplierFirstName(String supplierFirstName) {
        this.supplierFirstName = supplierFirstName;
    }

    public String getSupplierLastName() {
        return this.supplierLastName;
    }

    public void setSupplierLastName(String supplierLastName) {
        this.supplierLastName = supplierLastName;
    }

    public String getSupplierPhone() {
        return this.supplierPhone;
    }

    public void setSupplierPhone(String supplierPhone) {
        this.supplierPhone = supplierPhone;
    }

    public List<WdLeafPurchase> getWdLeafPurchases() {
        return this.wdLeafPurchases;
    }

    public void setWdLeafPurchases(List<WdLeafPurchase> wdLeafPurchases) {
        this.wdLeafPurchases = wdLeafPurchases;
    }

    public WdCollectionCenter getWdCollectionCenter() {
        return this.wdCollectionCenter;
    }

    public void setWdCollectionCenter(WdCollectionCenter wdCollectionCenter) {
        this.wdCollectionCenter = wdCollectionCenter;
    }

    public List<WdSupplierLoan> getWdSupplierLoans() {
        return this.wdSupplierLoans;
    }

    public void setWdSupplierLoans(List<WdSupplierLoan> wdSupplierLoans) {
        this.wdSupplierLoans = wdSupplierLoans;
    }

}
```

How can i fix this error ?

Comment: Start by sharing the code of the entity.

Comment: @JBNizet Question updated with the Link to Entity Class.

Comment: This sounds like a stupid question, but is it set in the database? Because the default field for this column is null. Can you append your question with the row you're trying to get from the db?

Comment: Post your code here. Not on dropbox.

Comment: @JBNizet It has 170 lines. ok, i'll post it here.

Comment: @Sam yes. it has a value as 'on'

Comment: @JBNizet post updated as required.

Comment: @Sam post updated as required.

Comment: You're probably not using the correct database, or the 'on' values that you're seeing have not been committed yet.

Comment: @JBNizet i'm using correct database and all values committed successfully. because i have restarted my PC and check the database and value is exists.